# Does this sentence need a preposition or article

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice

That work made poor coaching but great training.

Idea being communicated is that the work wouldn't be considered "good coaching" but it was "good training." Note that I am not using an article before good coaching or training.

One could say "That work make a poor coaching but a great training," but this would express a different idea -- an idea of a specific instance of coaching/training not generic coaching/training.

Also, one could add a preposition or some other verb form needed for it to make it look correct, but that may again communicate a different idea than what's desired.
E.g. "X led to poor coaching" or "X made up for poor coaching".

Is the original correct grammatically?

Comment: If the idea is "*education*", why use "*coaching*". 

**"That work is poor education but great training,"** 

seems like the most straightforward expression to me.

Comment: That was a typo (upvoted for notifying). I have corrected it to coaching throughout.

Comment: Do you intend to say something like "A good coach would have a hard time using that work to coach, but any person could be trained by it?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the original rendering is correct.
Your subsequent conjectures are irrelevant. Neither "coaching" nor "training" are countable nouns, so it would not be appropriate to write "a coaching" or "a training" unless you used them as adjectives: "a coaching program" , "a training session".

Comment: this is incorrect. coaching/training can be used in the countable sense. Just as you say "it was a great coaching experience."

Comment: And just as I said, it is not appropriate to use "a" with "coaching" or "training" used as NOUNS. In the example you threw back at me, the NOUN being counted is "experience".

Comment: I can see the noun coaching being used in countable sense too. It's a matter of style. Unless you can justify what you say based on a citation it's your style is just one of many.

Comment: @JoeBlack Can you find any evidence at all, from dictionaries, or printed books, for example, that *coaching* is normally countable?